# How to extract files from across multiple folders in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, glob, os.walk

Essentially... I have 27 folders on a local drive, each comprising tens of thousands of .jpgs. I have generated a random list of 5,000 of these images, distributed accross the 27 folders, that I wish to transfer into one folder.

I have a .csv list of all the 5,000 filenames I need, and was wondering what the easiest way to get these all into one folder would be?

I see plenty of onine resources explaing how to achieve this using 'glob.glob' and 'os.walk' methods to extract all files with a specific file extension (e.g. .txt), however I need to extract them based on the specific filenames that I have in a list.

I generally work in Python, but if there's another obvious non-coding way of doing this without it that I'm missing, please do suggest that too.

Thanks, R

Answer (score 1):

This is a relatively basic Python solution, but maybe you can tweak it to something more useful.

```
import csv
import os
import shutil

# Generator for all files in root_dir
def list_files(my_root_dir):
    for path, _, files in os.walk(my_root_dir):
        yield path, files


def copy_files(my_csv_file, my_root_dir, my_target_dir):
    with open(my_csv_file, "r") as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        for line in csv_reader:
            for image in line:
                for path, files in list_files(my_root_dir):
                    # Careful not to copy files already copied to target_dir
                    if image in files and path != my_target_dir:
                        shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, image), my_target_dir)
                        break
```

If you want to stick to the shell, there are some ideas here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402728/how-to-move-files-specified-in-a-text-file-to-another-directory-on-bash.